# How to join same table again and again till a condition in single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named category with three columns.

1. Category ID (Unique Auto Inc id)
2. Category Name
3. Category Parent (Unique id of parent from same table. If no 0)

I can have any number of in depth child's. The requirement is to get all categories with its parent child relation in one query.

The output should be...

- Category 1
- Category 1 -> Category 2 (assuming category 2's parent is category 1)
- Category 1 -> Category 2 -> Category 3 (assuming category 3's parent is category 2)

Likewise it should return everything with hierarchy. Can anyone help me with that ?

Comment: This is a basic question about managing hierarchical data

Comment: it's also a "do my work for me" question

Comment: this may be useful: **[articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)**.

Comment: thanks Ryan... that link was informative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rayan Vincent. I just got idea from the link you have mentioned.

Am not sure this is the efficient way of getting it... but the output is coming as expected. Am writing the query here as it may be helpful if anyone look for similar one. This results fine up to 4th level of child.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t4.category_id as id, t4.category_name AS lev1, t3.category_name as lev2, t2.category_name as lev3, t1.category_name as lev4 FROM categories AS t1 RIGHT JOIN categories AS t2 ON t2.category_parent = t1.category_id RIGHT JOIN categories AS t3 ON t3.category_parent = t2.category_id RIGHT JOIN categories AS t4 ON t4.category_parent = t3.category_id
```